# Download WoW information using Lua and NexusHub

Tags: lua

lua beginner here. I am a data science student and am trying to analyze gathering professions in World of Warcraft by using auction house data to see which items from those professions sell for the most/most often.

To download this information, NexusHub has this great website that already stores all the information using an in-game addon. However, I said lua beginner in the beginning of this post and by that I mean I've been learning for about an hour. :)

Here's the NexusHub website for context: https://nexushub.co/developers/api/Wow-Classic-Items/items

I have no idea how to download this. I looked at a few unrelated examples and saw some statements like

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local body, code = http.request("ENTER URL HERE")
```

but I'm still unsure if I'm headed in the right direction.

Could someone give me some pointers on where to go?

Comment: The HTTP examples you posted are written in Luasocket, the library for Lua that provides all kinds of network support. https://luarocks.org/modules/luasocket/luasocket   http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html  I don't often do networking so that's all the help I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

WoW addons normally save data whenever the game closes to the following location:

```
__[retail|classic]__/WTF/Account/[yourAccount]/SavedVariables/[yourAddon].lua
```

A typical WoW solution would be to gather your data, name it as a variable, exit the game, and then copy/paste the file from SavedVariables with the game closed.  Presumably you will have some way to parse that data outside the game.

For this to work, you must declare saved variable in the [.toc](https://wow.gamepedia.com/TOC_format) file.